# Redshift user with default access to newly created schemas

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Is there a way for an AWS Redshift user to have select only access on *newly created* schemas created by a separate Redshift user?

For example, if I create a user as follows:

```
   CREATE USER francesco_totti WITH PASSWORD xxxxxx;

   GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA "forza_roma" to francesco_totti;

   GRANT SELECT on all TABLES in schema "forza_roma" to francesco_totti;

   ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA "forza_roma" GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO francesco_totti;
```

How can I grant the ***francesco_totti*** user access to schemas that are created later on by a separate user? I want to alter the default privileges to allow ***francesco_totti*** to read from newly created schemas. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible as It's against the data security policy. We need to provide Authorization and access to each individual user or user group. What you can do is create a group and provide access